# Send a number value from one component to another component in Angular2

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I had searched but failed to integrate then in my project.
**Problem:**I have to send a variable contains number,to a component.ts from component.ts . Note: I don't want that value in HTML page.
Below i have given a sample example,how i want the data!!

```
child.component.ts
===================
export class Child{

x:number;
<!-- may be some code to send the x value-->
<!-- Remember the value is in a method,which is onclick of a button-->

  onButtonClick(){

   x=5;

  }
}

parent.component.ts
====================
export class parent{

<!--some code goes here to get the x value-->

console.log("The value of x from Child: ",x);

}
```

Now as like above code,i want the value of x in the component and show that value in the console.
Thanks for brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Output & EventEmitter` properties.

```
// parent.component.ts
// ==================== 

export class parent{
    updateValue(newValue: any){
        console.log("The value of x from Child: ", newValue);
    }
}

// parent.component.html
// ====================

<child (childValue)="updateValue($event)"></child>

// child.component.ts
// ===================

import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class Child{
    @Output() childValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    onButtonClick(){
        this.childValue.emit('value here');
    }
}
```

Comment: ,i want to know whether <child (childValue)="updateValue($event)"></child> has to written in HTML or in .ts file?

Comment: I don't think,this,i can write in .ts file...My query is to get that x value in .ts file like above code.

Comment: This should be written in html. whenever the value emitted from the child, the `updateValue()` funtion , which is in the parent .ts file will be invoked

Comment: can you please able to comment below what to write in .ts file?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the **reactive programming** approach for this issue. You can see the implementation in the code below.

Here is the **Child** component as service *(keep in mind that services need to be provided before usage)*.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ChildService {
    public x$: Observable<string>;
    private x: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.x = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
        this.x$ = this.x.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Since we are using reactive programming, when the value of **x** in the **Child** service changes, we will have the updated value in the **Parent** component as well because we are **subscribed** to the value changes.

Here is the **Parent** component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ChildService } from './child.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
    x: string;

    constructor(childService: ChildService) {
        childService.x$.subscribe((value: string) => {
            this.x = value;
        });
    }
}
```

***Keep in mind that Child is a service (and not component) and needs to be provided in an @NgModule***

```
import { ChildService } from './child.service';

@NgModule({
    // ....
    providers: [
        ChildService
    ]
    // ....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: how change variable x in ChildService ?

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes you will need a method in the ChildService for that one. Something like

setX(value: string) {
    this.x.next(value);
  }

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers overcomplicate things. For direct parent -> child or child -> parent communication, you can simply use dependency injection, the same technique you may often use to inject other Angular classes in constructors when components are instantiated.

Lets say you have some parent component

```
export class ParentComponent {

   someString: string;

   constructor( )  {} 

   someMethod() {
      return someVal : any;
   }

   private somePrivateMethod() {  return 'cant touch this'  }
}
```

In any of its children, you can inject the instance of that parent component as a parameter in the childcomponents constructor. You just need to import it like you do other classes.

```
import { ParentComponent } from './wherever/parent/is/'

export class ChildComponent { 

   constructor(private parent:ParentComponent) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      let abc = this.parent.someMethod(); // works bc method is public
      let nope = this.parent.somePrivateMethod(); // will throw a compile error
    }
}
```

Any public methods or properties of the parent component will now be accessible in by the child using this.parent.whatever.

For communication back to the parent, you can create an object in the parent component that stores instances of the ChildComponent. So similarly, import the ChildComponent into the ParentComponent file.

```
import { ChildComponent } from './wherever/child/is'

export class ParentComponent {

   someString: string;
   someNum: number;
   arrayOfChildren: ChildComponent[] = [];

   constructor( )  {} 

   someMethod() {
       return someVal : any;
   }

   addChild( child: ChildComponent ) {
      this.arrayOfChildren.push(child);
    } 
}
```

And then add some method in the parent component that adds instances of its child components to an array (probably better to use a map, but I'm keeping it simple for now).

Then in the child, you just call that method in the parent that adds children

```
export class ChildComponent { 
   constructor(private parent:ParentComponent) { }

   ngOnInit() {
        this.parent.addChild(this);
   }
}
```

Now your child can access public properties of parent via this.parent, and your parent can access public properties of its children via  this.arrayOfChildren[0]. Reactive programming is great, but its great for when communication is required between directives / components that aren't directly hierarchially related. There are much simpler options when you have direct relationships.

Note: the only reason I chose an array is bc typically parents have many descendants. There's no reason you couldn't just create a property called

```
myChild: ChildComponent;
```

and store the child directly to that.

Comment: Can you please explain it how to write this in my code.Which i was mentioned above.

Comment: i am still waiting @diopside

Answer (score 0):

Adopting my example to your provided code....

```
import { Parent } from './locationofparent'


@Component({selector: 'child'})
export class Child{

 constructor(private parent: Parent) {  }

 x:number;
  <!-- may be some code to send the x value // just need to have the parent read it-->
  <!-- Remember the value is in a method,which is onclick of a button-->

  ngOnInit() { 
     this.parent.addChild(this);
  }

  onButtonClick(){

   this.x=5;

  }
```

}

================================

```
import { Child } from './locationofchild'

@Component({selector: 'child' })
export class Parent{

   constructor()  { }

   child: Child;

    addChild(myChild: Child) {
       this.child = myChild;
    }

   someOtherMethod(){   
       console.log(this.child.x)  <--- will print 5, assuming 5 has been set by the click, otherwise it will print undefined
   }
}
```